# Is assert in privation function redundant if check has already been made by the calling public function?

Tags: exception, nullpointerexception

Effective java states a good practice of assertions in private methods.

"For an unexported method, you as the package author control the circumstances under which the method is called, so you can and should ensure that only valid parameter values are ever passed in. Therefore, nonpublic methods should generally check their parameters using assertions, as shown below:

For example:

```
// Private helper function for a recursive sort
private static void sort(long a[]) {
    assert a != null;
    // Do the computation;
}
```

My question is would asserts be required even if the public function calling the sort has a null pointer check ?

Example:

```
public void computeTwoNumbersThatSumToInputValue(int a[], int x) {
    if (a == null) {
      throw new Nullptrexception();
    }
    sort(a);
    // code to do the required.
}
```

In other words, will asserts in private function be 'redudant' or mandatory in this case.

Thanks,

Comment: Side-note: prefer `int[] a` over `int a[]`; the latter syntax is only supported for legacy reasons, and the former is preferred as a matter of style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's redundant if you're *sure* that you've got the assertion in all the calling code. In some cases, that's very obvious - in other cases it can be less so. If you're calling `sort` from 20 places in the class, are you sure you've checked it in every case?

It's a matter of taste and balance, with no "one size fits all" answer. The balance is in terms of code clarity (both ways!), performance (in extreme cases) and of course safety. It depends on the exact context, and I wouldn't personally like to even guarantee that I'm entirely consistent. (In other words, "level of caffeine at the time of coding" may turn out to be an influence too.)

Note that your `assert` is only going to execute when assertions are turned on anyway - I personally prefer to validate parameters consistently however you're running the code. I generally use the [`Preconditions`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) class from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) to make preconditions unobtrusive.

Answer (score 0):

Assertions will make the helper function sort more robust to use.
Checking for parameters before passing it to any method is a good methodology to have more control over the Exceptions occurring unintentionally at the runtime.

My suggestion will be to use both the approaches in your code as there is no guarantee that all the callers of sort will do such checks. If assertions in helper methods are algorithmically of high order or seems redundant then this can be disabled (esp for production use) via use of -disableassertions or -da from command-line.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that. I will quote from the [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) docs.

> An assertion is a statement in the JavaTM programming language that
>   enables you to test your assumptions about your program. For example,
>   if you write a method that calculates the speed of a particle, you
>   might assert that the calculated speed is less than the speed of
>   light.

I do not personally use assertions, but from what I gathered readings the oracle docs on it, it enables you to test your assumptions about what you expect something to do. Try/catch blocks are more for failing gracefully as an inevitability of failures bound to happen (like networking, computer problems). Basically, in a perfect world your code would always run successfully because theres nothing wrong with it code wise. But this isn't a perfect world. Also note:

> Experience has shown that writing assertions while programming is one
>   of the quickest and most effective ways to detect and correct bugs. As
>   an added benefit, assertions serve to document the inner workings of
>   your program, enhancing maintainability.

I would say use as a preference. To answer your question, I would mainly use it to test code as the docs say, while testing assumptions you have about your code. As the second quote mentions, it has the added benefit of telling other developers (or future you) what you assume to get as parameters. As a personal preference, I leave control flow to try/catch blocks as that is what they were designed for.

*But keep in mind that assertions could be turned off.

Comment: Any reason you've written those grey parts as code blocks? It makes them much harder to read. Assuming they're quotes, it would also be helpful to link to the page you're quoting from.

Comment: Better @JonSkeet? Thanks for pointing that out. I'm going to be honest and say I had no idea there was an option for quotes, and I just forgot to add the source.

Comment: @Andy: Better, although it isn't really answering the question IMO. Your answer is only about whether assertions are a good idea, whereas the question is about writing private method assertions that have already been tested in the calling code.